# Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate()

Tags: php, laravel

why am i getting this error?

Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, instance of Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\spupresearchjournal\app\Http\Controllers\CurrentIssueController.php on line 55

public function store(Request $request)
    {

```
    $this->validate($request, [

        'journalcover' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'title' => 'required',
        'editor' => 'required',
        'date' => 'required',
        'summary' => 'required',
    ]);

    // check if file was uploaded
    if ($request->hasFile('journalcover')) {
        // get the file object
        $image = $request->file('journalcover');
        $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        //$name['journalcover'] = 'images/' . $request->file('journalcover')->getClientOriginalName();
        //$size = $image->getClientSize();
        $destinationPath = ('images/');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
        $journalcover = $destinationPath . $name;

        $newjournal = new CurrentIssue;
        $newjournal->journalcover = ('images/').$name;
        $newjournal->title = $request->input('title');
        $newjournal->editor = $request->input('editor');
        $newjournal->date = $request->input('date');
        $newjournal->summary = $request->input('summary');
        $newjournal->status = $request->input('status', '0');
        //$newjournal->size = $size;
        //dd($newjournal);
        $newjournal->save();

        return redirect('/currentissue')->with('success', 'New Journal Added');
    }
}
```

Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, instance of Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\spupresearchjournal\app\Http\Controllers\CurrentIssueController.php on line 55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't import the class from the correct namespace in your controller.  You'd want the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class imported at the top of your file, not the Request facade class:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php about using namespaces.